# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' and 'android' while running ionic

Tags: android, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I am getting following error when I am running `sudo ionic build android`

`Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.`

`Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.`

I have unzipped android-sdk inside '/opt'.android command runs fine from terminal.

I am setting my $ANDROID_HOME in ~/.bashrc

`export ANDROID_HOME="/opt"
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME
 export PATH=$PATH:/opt/platform-tools
 export PATH=$PATH:/opt/tools`

`echo $ANDROID_HOME` gives `/opt`.

`echo $PATH` gives `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/arvind/workspace:/opt:/opt/platform-tools:/opt/tools`

P.S.: Running android from terminal gives following warning.( Don't know if it matters ).

`(Android SDK Manager:6041): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/user1/.config/ibus/bus is not root!`

Comment: Is the path to android SDk "/opt" or "/opt/android-sdk"?

Comment: @asalic I have unzipped sdk in opt itself.So, opt/platform-tools and opt/tools exist.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Operating System or Mac operation System?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed ionic globally(use `sudo npm install -g ionic`), you should not add `sudo` when you use ionic cli command. Just use:

```
ionic platform rm android
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
```

Hope this will help you, regards!

Answer (score 0):

you just have to point out the bin directory inside android studio as:

`inside ~/.bashrc`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android-studio/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```

now `echo $PATH` and make sure the android studio is included in the path.